# How to keep AlertDialog on top of DialogFragment on rotation change

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` which on click of a button will open an `AlertDialog`, which, in this case, is the `dialog` from this [library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs). When I rotate the device I can keep the `AlertDialog` from disappearing, but it is behind the `DialogFragment`. How can I make it so it stays on top of it?

**Material dialog**

```
mDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .title(R.string.email_sent)
            .content(R.string.check_email)
            .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
            .positiveText(R.string.send)
            .negativeText(R.string.cancel)
            .inputRange(1, 10, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.red_900))
            .input(R.string.activation_code, 0, new MaterialDialog.InputCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onInput(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    int userActivationCode = Integer.parseInt(input.toString());
                    peem.setActivationCode(userActivationCode);
                    mPresenter.createActivationCodePeem(peem);
                }
            }).onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
    DisplayUtil.keepDialog(mDialog);
```

**Keeping the dialog on rotation change**

```
public static void keepDialog(MaterialDialog dialog) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    params.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
}
```

Comment: destroying and rebuilding the AlertDialog? You should not trying to retain the Dialog on screen, instead save state if needed and when rotation change is completed re-open the dialog with the old data

Comment: @MatPag How would I do that?

Comment: Try to read here for some tips on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10734867/2910520

Comment: I did try destroying and rebuilding the dialog, but it is still behind the `DialogFragment`

Comment: Are you sure you are re-creating the dialog after the DialogFragment is added to the view? You probably need to create you AlertDialog after onCreateDialog or onCreateView of you DialogFragment, or trying to listen to onAttach event from parent Activity or Fragment